# Получение значение из другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс (1), в котором содержатся несколько приватных полей (назовем их цена, количество, цвет). Для них уже сделаны геттеры. На сцене имеются несколько UI.Text. Мне нужно, чтобы при появлении этих UI.Text, в них выводилось соответствующее значение полей класса (1). Как это сделать?

Comment: Повесить на  UI.Text скрипт который считает значения полей твоего класса  и присвоит их  UI.Text. Класс можно передать как параметр через редактор.... проблема не раскрыта.

Comment: В данном случае тогда мне нужно повесить функцию (Я не знаю как). Потому что один UI.Text выводит одно значение.

Comment: что значит повесить функцию? вешаете компонент с методами на объект (например на canvas). При старте обращаетесь к компоненту на канвасе и к его методам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в данном случае один "текст" должен вызывать GetColor(), другой "текст" GetPrice() и третий GetCount(). Может, в Unity можно указывать какой метод вызывать (как OnClick() в кнопке).

Comment: скрипт с методами где висит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на другом Game Object

Answer (score 7):

У объектов есть метод **[Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)**,  который находит объект с именем `name` и возвращает его. Можно воспользоваться им, как один **из вариантов**.

Пример:

```
public GameObject hand;

void Example() {
    hand = GameObject.Find("Hand");
    hand = GameObject.Find("/Hand");
    hand = GameObject.Find("/Monster/Arm/Hand");
    hand = GameObject.Find("Monster/Arm/Hand");
}
```

где строка в методе — это путь до объекта в иерархии сцены. Слэш означает искать от корня (то есть будет произведен обход иерархии, как если бы вместо имени был указан путь).

Соответственно, при старте `Start()` находите объект через `Find`, и даете ему значение, взятое из метода. Что-то типа:

```
GameObject.Find("/Canvas/MyData/PriceText").GetComponent<Text>().text = GetPrice();
GameObject.Find("/Canvas/MyData/CountText").GetComponent<Text>().text = GetCount();
```

---

### Небольшое дополнение (если можно так назвать)...

Вообще, на самом деле, скрипты на *UI.Text* и прочих *UI*, которые **берут данные откуда-то с другого скрипты** вам особо и **не нужны**. Часто делают *Менеджеров (Managers)*, которые ответственны за некую общую сущность. 
Например *UIManager*. Делается один скрипт, который управляет отображением в *UI*. Он слушает события и в зависимости от них производит нужные действия.

---

### Заметка (!!!):

О событиях, о слушателях и рассылках почитайте где-либо, особенно такую вещь как паттерны (шаблоны) проектирования и, в частности, паттерн "наблюдатель (Observer)". Потому что рассылка сообщений основывается именно на данном нём.

---

Итак, прежде всего нужен скрипт рассылки сообщений, назовём его `Messenger.cs`, с помощью методов которого и работает менеджер. Его код можно взять по **[данной ссылке](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSharpMessenger)** или посмотреть под спойлером:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 
public enum MessengerMode {
 DONT_REQUIRE_LISTENER,
 REQUIRE_LISTENER,
}
 
static internal class MessengerInternal {
 readonly public static Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
 static public readonly MessengerMode DEFAULT_MODE = MessengerMode.REQUIRE_LISTENER;
 
  static public void AddListener(string eventType, Delegate callback) {
  MessengerInternal.OnListenerAdding(eventType, callback);
  eventTable[eventType] = Delegate.Combine(eventTable[eventType], callback);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Delegate handler) {
  MessengerInternal.OnListenerRemoving(eventType, handler); 
  eventTable[eventType] = Delegate.Remove(eventTable[eventType], handler);
  MessengerInternal.OnListenerRemoved(eventType);
 }
 
 static public T[] GetInvocationList<T>(string eventType) {
  Delegate d;
  if(eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d)) {
   if(d != null) {
    return d.GetInvocationList().Cast<T>().ToArray();
   } else {
    throw MessengerInternal.CreateBroadcastSignatureException(eventType);
   }
  }
  return null;
 }
 
 static public void OnListenerAdding(string eventType, Delegate listenerBeingAdded) {
  if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType)) {
   eventTable.Add(eventType, null);
  }
 
  var d = eventTable[eventType];
  if (d != null && d.GetType() != listenerBeingAdded.GetType()) {
   throw new ListenerException(string.Format("Attempting to add listener with inconsistent signature for event type {0}. Current listeners have type {1} and listener being added has type {2}", eventType, d.GetType().Name, listenerBeingAdded.GetType().Name));
  }
 }
 
 static public void OnListenerRemoving(string eventType, Delegate listenerBeingRemoved) {
  if (eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType)) {
   var d = eventTable[eventType];
 
   if (d == null) {
    throw new ListenerException(string.Format("Attempting to remove listener with for event type {0} but current listener is null.", eventType));
   } else if (d.GetType() != listenerBeingRemoved.GetType()) {
    throw new ListenerException(string.Format("Attempting to remove listener with inconsistent signature for event type {0}. Current listeners have type {1} and listener being removed has type {2}", eventType, d.GetType().Name, listenerBeingRemoved.GetType().Name));
   }
  } else {
   throw new ListenerException(string.Format("Attempting to remove listener for type {0} but Messenger doesn't know about this event type.", eventType));
  }
 }
 
 static public void OnListenerRemoved(string eventType) {
  if (eventTable[eventType] == null) {
   eventTable.Remove(eventType);
  }
 }
 
 static public void OnBroadcasting(string eventType, MessengerMode mode) {
  if (mode == MessengerMode.REQUIRE_LISTENER && !eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType)) {
   throw new MessengerInternal.BroadcastException(string.Format("Broadcasting message {0} but no listener found.", eventType));
  }
 }
 
 static public BroadcastException CreateBroadcastSignatureException(string eventType) {
  return new BroadcastException(string.Format("Broadcasting message {0} but listeners have a different signature than the broadcaster.", eventType));
 }
 
 public class BroadcastException : Exception {
  public BroadcastException(string msg)
   : base(msg) {
  }
 }
 
 public class ListenerException : Exception {
  public ListenerException(string msg)
   : base(msg) {
  }
 }
}
 
// No parameters
static public class Messenger { 
 static public void AddListener(string eventType, Action handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void AddListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Action handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType) {
  Broadcast(eventType, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, Action<TReturn> returnCall) {
  Broadcast(eventType, returnCall, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
  static public void Broadcast(string eventType, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Action>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var callback in invocationList)
   callback.Invoke();
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, Action<TReturn> returnCall, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Func<TReturn>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var result in invocationList.Select(del => del.Invoke()).Cast<TReturn>()) {
   returnCall.Invoke(result);
  }
 }
}
 
// One parameter
static public class Messenger<T> {
 static public void AddListener(string eventType, Action<T> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void AddListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Action<T> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, Action<TReturn> returnCall) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, returnCall, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Action<T>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var callback in invocationList)
   callback.Invoke(arg1);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, Action<TReturn> returnCall, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Func<T, TReturn>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var result in invocationList.Select(del => del.Invoke(arg1)).Cast<TReturn>()) {
   returnCall.Invoke(result);
  }
 }
}
 
 
// Two parameters
static public class Messenger<T, U> { 
 static public void AddListener(string eventType, Action<T, U> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void AddListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, U, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Action<T, U> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, U, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, arg2, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, Action<TReturn> returnCall) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, arg2, returnCall, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Action<T, U>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var callback in invocationList)
   callback.Invoke(arg1, arg2);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, Action<TReturn> returnCall, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Func<T, U, TReturn>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var result in invocationList.Select(del => del.Invoke(arg1, arg2)).Cast<TReturn>()) {
   returnCall.Invoke(result);
  }
 }
}
 
 
// Three parameters
static public class Messenger<T, U, V> { 
 static public void AddListener(string eventType, Action<T, U, V> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void AddListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, U, V, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.AddListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Action<T, U, V> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void RemoveListener<TReturn>(string eventType, Func<T, U, V, TReturn> handler) {
  MessengerInternal.RemoveListener(eventType, handler);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, V arg3) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, arg2, arg3, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, Action<TReturn> returnCall) {
  Broadcast(eventType, arg1, arg2, arg3, returnCall, MessengerInternal.DEFAULT_MODE);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Action<T, U, V>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var callback in invocationList)
   callback.Invoke(arg1, arg2, arg3);
 }
 
 static public void Broadcast<TReturn>(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, Action<TReturn> returnCall, MessengerMode mode) {
  MessengerInternal.OnBroadcasting(eventType, mode);
  var invocationList = MessengerInternal.GetInvocationList<Func<T, U, V, TReturn>>(eventType);
 
  foreach(var result in invocationList.Select(del => del.Invoke(arg1, arg2, arg3)).Cast<TReturn>()) {
   returnCall.Invoke(result);
  }
 }
}
```

Еще есть события в  игре. Например вспомогательный скрипт `GameEvent.cs` будет их в себе содержать:

```
public static class GameEvent {
    public const string GAME_STARTED = "GAME_STARTED";
    public const string ITEM_BOUGHT = "ITEM_BOUGHT";
    public const string SPEED_CHANGED = "SPEED_CHANGED";

    // ... и т.д.
}
```

В менеджере (UIManager) подписываемся на событие, в данном случае на то, что игра стартовала `GAME_STARTED` и , например `ITEM_BOUGHT` (когда предмет покупаем, наверняка меняется их количество?).

```
public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Text colorLabel;
    [SerializeField] private Text priceLabel;
    [SerializeField] private Text countLabel;

    private MyDataClass myDataClass;

    void Awake() {
        // подписываемся на события и указываем методы, которые будут вызваны при возникновение этого события
        Messenger.AddListener(GameEvent.GAME_STARTED, OnGameStarted);
        Messenger.AddListener(GameEvent.ITEM_BOUGHT, OnItemBought);
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        Messenger.RemoveListener(GameEvent.GAME_STARTED, OnGameStarted);
        Messenger.RemoveListener(GameEvent.ITEM_BOUGHT, OnItemBought);
    }

    // будет вызван при получении события GAME_STARTED
    private void OnGameStarted() {  
        myDataClass = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/MyData/MyClassObject").gameObject.GetComponent<MyClass>();

        colorLabel.text = myDataClass.GetColor().ToString();
        priceLabel.text = myDataClass.GetPrice().ToString();
        countLabel.text = myDataClass.GetCount().ToString();
    }

    // будет вызван при получении события ITEM_BOUGHT
    private void OnItemBought() {
        countLabel.text = myDataClass.GetCount().ToString();
    }
}
```

Скрипт вешается на пустой объект на сцене, который желательно тоже так же назвать: "UIManager". В поля скрипта (которые bv.n атрибут `SerializeField`) добавить нужные объекты (в данном случае текстовые объекты *UI.Text*) и всё.

Теперь в любой момент, на любом нужном скрипте рассылаем сообщения. Например на каком-нибудь главном скрипте `Game.cs`

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        // Уведомляем, что игра началась
        Messenger.Broadcast(GameEvent.GAME_STARTED);
    }
}
```

Или в каком-то другом скрипте, который ответственен за покупку предметов

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {
    public void OnPointerDown() {
        _count++;
        // Уведомляем, что предмет куплен
        Messenger.Broadcast(GameEvent.ITEM_BOUGHT);
    }
}
```

Запускаем игру и радуемся.

Так системка делается-то...

Comment: Вы, наверное, не так поняли. На Text уже есть скрипт, но он не знает что вызывать при появлении : GetPrice, GetCount, GetColor ... Через инспектор мне нужно ему как то указать, какой из методов вызывать.

Comment: @NikitaMedvedev ну значит действовать в обратную сторону: в скрипте, который висит на `Text`  при старте искать тот объект в иерархии, который содержит метод и вызывать его.. `GetComponent<Text>().text  = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/MyData/MyClassObject").gameObject.GetComponent<MyClass>().GetPrice();` ....... просто вы неполно задачу описываете. я уже писал вам, что было бы хорошо если бы вы хотя бы визуально описывали задачу в вопросе что есть , что хотите и т.д., а не голым абстрактным текстом

Comment: @NikitaMedvedev добавил в ответ то, как по-человечески всё делается. Возможно будет полезна эта информация